# How to prevent render page from jumping in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, components

I have a vue application and I load async components.

The problem is the page render is jumping.

For example, in the picture I load header, intro, slide components (and more components after slide component)..

When I using `import('./...')` then I see that the slide component is first to render then header then the intro component. (this order is always change).

This is cause the page to be jump, the slide is going down and the intro is appear, which have bad ux.

I try to fix that by css grid - defined the template-column-rows (min size) but, the components are not there yet. so the wrap div doesn't affect on the child components.

[image]

Here by this picture the header and the slide is already rendered, and after a few seconds the intro is appear..

[image]

Any idea how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you know ahead of time that the components are going to be loaded in, you could create wrapper `divs` in the parent component that loads these components. And add a `css grid` system to these wrapper `divs`, defining `height` etc.

This would prevent the jumping of elements around the page as new components are loaded in.

As you haven't shared any code, it's hard to tailor this answer to your specific needs. I hope it gives you an idea of what to do.

### Example

**Parent**

```html
<template>
   <div class="container">
      <div id="header__wrapper">
        <Header />
      </div>
      <div id="intro__wrapper">
         <Intro />
      </div>
     <div id="slide_wrapper">
         <Slide />
     </div>
</template>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* or whatever you need */
}
```